# how to Protect Php file with the htaccess to protevent external use or a direct use

Tags: php, .htaccess

If someone for exemple try to use my php script or an external use or also a direct use I want to deny him.
I have tried this in my htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com(/)?.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(php)$ / [NC,R,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, what I want is to allow the php script only when I call it in another page on my server.
The deny/allow way is also not perfect because it's possible to get the content of my php script by `CURL`.

Comment: Why don't you simply move it to a place inaccessible from the outside?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504385/blocking-direct-access/13504397#13504397), maybe will help.

Comment: because i use the script in an other page in my server so i can't use it too

Comment: thank you for reply [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504385/blocking-direct-access/13504397#13504397) deny me to use the script from me too

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule \.(php)$ / [NC,R,L]
```

Or without mod_rewrite:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: it diesn't work for me in local when i request the file protected with this.
In fact i have a php file which content a playlist (m3u8) in a folder.
Then i have a Flowplayer (in root) which work with this playlist, i want to protect this playlist, because other websites steal it.

Comment: The Flowplayer requests are made from the client, not from the server.